# Как создать начальный скрипт для сцены?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пока только начинаю разбираться с unity3d)
Мне бы хотелось, чтобы при переходе на сцену сперва выполнялся определенный скрипт (установка начальных параметров для всех объектов) а уже потом все другие скрипты)
Как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так:

```
var a,b,c;

void Init()
{
a = 5;
b = 3;
c = 6;
}

void Start() 
{
StartCoroutine(Init());//Выполнение в основном потоке
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 - все объекты кроме одного заблокировать, на незаблокированный объект повесить скрипт, который будет выполнять действие, а затем - разблокировать все остальные объекты.

Вариант 1.2 - все объекты поместить в объект-контейнер, тогда заблокировать достаточно только объект-контейнер.

Вариант 2 - создать глобальную булеву переменную, на всех скриптах проверять ее значение. В главном скрипте по завершении выполнения присвоить этой переменной true.

Comment: @GenkaOk а чем не угодил Awake()? :)